# Resetting Windows drivers

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, android, device-manager

Is there a way to "start over" with all the drivers on Windows 7?

I've been having trouble for days now trying to install drivers for my Android devices. I keep getting "Access is denied" error, although the device manager says it found the right drivers. I've tried all the tips I found online (clearing the registry, making sure I am the administrator, trying different drivers, reducing the UAC to the ground, etc..)

Now things messed up and I cannot even read my USB drive, and yesterday the mouse and keyboard stopped working when I unplugged them and plugged them back!

So before I reinstall my Windows, I wanted to see if I can reset my drivers to factory settings or doing something like that. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're having is a registry one. I've seen this myself before. For some reason windows adds a key to one or more keys, and due to that it no longer properly detects the hardware. So in a way, when you remove those keys, it'll reset your drivers.

Here's what you need to do.

1. Open Regedit
2. Navigate to the following key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class`
3. Right click the Class key and choose Export.
4. Save this to a regfile (your backup in case it doesn't work)
5. Go by each subkey, and on the right look for a string called UpperFilters and delete all
6. Do the same for LowerFilters and delete them.
7. Close the registry and reboot your system
8. Plug in your device and see if it will now be properly installed.